# Can we have healthcheck Rest API exposed from Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

Was wondering if we could have some REST APIs exposed from Kafka, that can be used for health checks or anything as such?

If haven't found any blogs giving relevant information.

Comment: last time I checked, Kafka didn't have any rest endpoint. It was there only for schema-registry. I believe that's the case even now.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka does not provide a REST API, but Confluent has developed a [REST proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html) to produce/consume from Kafka. However it does not provide healthcheck information.

It depends what you mean by healthcheck, but [Kafka Monitor](https://github.com/linkedin/kafka-monitor) from Linkedin is quite nice to have an end-to-end view of your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need the REST API for the health checks, the following repository might be what you need: https://github.com/andreas-schroeder/kafka-health-check

Answer (score 0):

You could add JMX agents like Jolokia or Prometheus JMX exporters, which expose all JMX data over HTTP.

From there, you can gather that data into Prometheus Server, for example, and correlate what defines an unhealthy cluster, such as URP or high heap usage, etc.

Non HTTP/pull based solutions also exist like Telegraf or Datadog.

Confluent offers Control Center, which might expose a some level of cluster health from an API